# Trouble using media queries for email design in Hotmail(Outlook)

Tags: iphone, media-queries, html-email, hotmail

I’m trying to design an email template that is also optimised for iPhone and later for Android if possible.
I’ve created a different header with the class “mobileheader”  for the header and a navigation menu with the class “mobilenav” and it works fine in iPhone. The problem is that it’s supposed to be hidden in the email clients meaning they will show the desktop version This works fine in with Outlook.com, Gmail and Yahoo in Safari, Firefox and Chrome and also in Outlook 2010 but in IE9, Outlook.com shows the mobile version menus,  this can be fixed refreshing the page but obviously it’s far from ideal.
I’ve checked the code an run several tests but I don’t know where the problem might be so any help would be great.

This is the code for the CSS which is located just after the wrapper (100%) table:

```
    <style type="text/css">
a{text-decoration:none;}
.ExternalClass * {line-height: 100%}
.ExternalClass {width:100%;}                          
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font,        .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {  line-height: 100%; }
body {margin:0; padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;}         
table td {border-collapse: collapse;}          
p {margin:0; padding:0; margin-bottom:0;line-height:100%;}       
.no-mobile{display:table;}
.contenttable1{width:600px;}
.contenttable{width:600px;}
.mobilenav{display:none !important;}
.mobileheader{display:none;}
.mobilelogo img{width:1px;height;1px;}
.web-version{font-size:1px;color:#FFFFFF;}  

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

table[class="no-mobile"]{
    display:none !important;
}
table[class="contenttable1"]{
    width:320px !important;
}   
table[class="contenttable"]{
    width:320px !important;
}
table[class="centeredtable"]{
    text-align:center;
}
table[class="mobilenav"]{
    display:block !important;
}
table[class="mobilenav"] td img{
    width:600px !important;
}

table[class="mobileheader"]{
    display:block !important;
}   
table[class="logo"]{
    width:320px !important;
}
table[class="header"]{
    width:320px !important;
}
td[class="mobilelogo"]{
    height:60px;
}   
td[class="mobilelogo"] img{
    text-align:left;
    width:200px;
    height:60px;
}
td[class="mobiletext"]{
    height:60px;
}   
td[class="innerspacer15"] img{
    text-align:center;
}
span.[class="web-version"],font.[class="web-version"]{
    font-size:13px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
span[class="web-version"]{
    text-align:right !important;
    color:#000000 !important;
    font-size:13px !important;
    font-family:'Arial',Verdana,Sans-Serif !important;
    font-weight:normal !important;  
}
font[class="orangelink"]{
    text-align:right !important;    
    color:#FF5800;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:'Arial',Verdana,Sans-Serif;
    font-weight:normal;     
}
}
```

And this the code for the header and navigation:

```
                        <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" width="600">
                        <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" class="no-mobile">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="157"><a href="~" target="_blank"><img src="image.gif" alt="Logo" width="157" height="54" border="0" style="display: block" /></a></td>
                                    <td align="right" style="text-align:right;line-height:0"><span style="font-family:'Arial',Verdana,Sans-Serif;color:#000000;font-size:13px">Problems seeing this email? <a href="#" target="_blank" style="font-family:'Arial',Verdana,Sans-Serif;color:#FF5800">Click here</a></span></td>                                  
                                    <td width="10" style="line-height:0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>    
                        </table>                                                    
                        <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="right" style="display:none;text-align:center" class="mobileheader" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="200" height="1" style="text-align:left;line-height:0" align="center" class="mobilelogo" ><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="image" alt="Logo" width="0" height="1" border="0" style="text-align:center" /></a></td>                               
                                    <td width="399" height="1" style="text-align:right;line-height:0" align="right" class="mobiletext"><span style="font-family:'Arial',Verdana,Sans-Serif;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:1px" class="web-version">Problems seeing this email?</span> <span style="font-family:'Arial',Verdana,Sans-Serif;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:1px"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:#FFFFFF" class="web-version"><font color="#FFFFFF" class="orangelink">Click here</font></a></span></td>                                                                   
                                </tr>    
                        </table>    
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

The mobile navigation has the class "mobilenav" and the inline style "display:none". I have tried to use display none !important in the inline style before but it didn't show the navigation in the iPhone so I had to change it.

Any help would be great.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It took me almost 2 days to figure out, here is the fix:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
```

Change `max-width` to `max-device-width`